# get new x/y positions of element after scroll using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, position

Lets say I have an `<a>` tag as follows:

```HTML
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="a1">Click Me</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

and my CSS are:

```css
body{ padding:10px;}
.wrapper { height:1000px; width:500px;}
```

Currently I am using `.offset()`  of Jquery to get the X/Y positions of `<a>` tag.

```js
var offset = $(".a1").offset();
var top = offset.top;
var left = offset.left;
```

Now when I scroll the page and check of `<a>` tag's x,y co-ordinates, they remain the same, i.e. ineffective of page scrolling.
I want to get the new X,Y positions of `<a>` tag after scrolling the page related to the screen.
If this `<a>` tag gets hidden after scrolling down, I want its position in negative values.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xQh5J/9/

Please help.

Comment: The element doesn't move just because you scrolled...

Comment: The x and y positions are the co-ordinates of the element with respect to where they exist in the DOM.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The link element's position w.r.t. the document *does not change when you scroll*. To get the position of the element w.r.t. the *window's* top-left, you can take it's *offset()* and subtract the window's scrollTop form what you get:

```
var offset = $(".a1").offset();
var w = $(window);
alert("(x,y): ("+(offset.left-w.scrollLeft())+","+(offset.top-w.scrollTop())+")");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xQh5J/10/

Comment: Thanks techfoobar for quick reply, i guess this is what I wanted...let me check!

Comment: hi @techfoobar your solution applies when window is scrolled but, what else to do when we scroll the inner div(having overflow:scroll) and get the element top position after scrolling the inner div which has list of items which is to be scrolled down and not the scrolling of window? please help..

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE you simple replace `var w = $(window);` with `var w = $('<selector>')` where `$('<selector>')` gets your div that has `overflow: scroll` instead of `window`.