# Asp.Net Form Validation - go the field which the error

Tags: asp.net, .net, scroll, field

I have a form on my website and when i hit the submit button I would like when there is field with an error for the page to scroll back to the field which has error.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

set the web page scroll position to that particular  control  position height. and set focus to that control.

[refer here to set page scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794700/get-new-x-y-positions-of-element-after-scroll-using-jquery)